# Oracle SQL - return some default value if query don't return results

Tags: sql, oracle

When run below query results is empty. Is it possible use some eg. NVL for return some value eg. -1

```
Select ename from emp where empno = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are expecting one row, you can use aggregation:

```
Select coalesce(max(ename), '-1')
from emp
where empno = 1;
```

This always returns one row, even when there is no match.